# List comprehension using an index to change the value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists with pairs of name strings

```
lst = [['Smith-Wilson J.', 'Johnson M.'],['Williams B-M.', 'Jones A.']]
```

Some of the abbreviated middle names come with a hyphen (e.g. `'Williams B-M.'`) and some of the last names have  a hyphen as well (e.g. `'Smith-Wilson J.'`).

I want to change only the hyphens attached to the abbreviated middle names to a dot (i.e. '.') using a list comprehension.

I know the index of the hyphen I want to change will always be `string[-3]`.

Output should look like this

```
lst = [['Smith-Wilson J.', 'Johnson M.'],['Williams B.M.', 'Jones A.']]
```

Comment: Change hyphens to _what_? Please post your expected output for that sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split the names the surnames will never be in the first position, right? Check for hyphens after the first name: `name.split().[1:]` your code can be something like this:

```
new_lst = [[" ".join([name.split()[0]]+list(map(lambda surname: surname.replace('-','.'), name.split()[1:]))) for name in pair] for pair in lst]
```

Comment: Almost there but it creates a list for each string. I need to keep the names as pairs of strings in a list. (i.e. ['Williams B.M.', 'Jones A.'] not [['Williams B.M.'],['Jones A.']]

Comment: Thanks will  concatenate the 2 lists to make the pairs single lists. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: The only issue with this is some names have a a surname with a space between 2 words so i think the best option is to use index[-3] AS CLEARLY SPECIFIED AND ARTICULATED IN THE INITIAL POST. If anyone can provide another solution it would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've worked it out, you need to use rsplit(' ', 1) to separate the first name abbreviation from the last names. Hope this helps anyone that found this post useful

Comment: sorry I forgot to join the names... I will edit it. With join there will be no problem with more than one name and the names will be in pairs

Comment: Now it is working properly even if the hyphen is not in the index -3 or if the name has more surnames

Comment: I will start studying lambda and map in more detail also. I'm noticing a lot of good programmers use it so it must add a lot of functionality.

Comment: @random In general prefer generator expressions/list comprehensions over `map` and use `lambda`s sparingly. Both `lambda` and `map` were almost going to be [dropped in Python 3](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).